# how to prevent app from crashing on Glide onResourceReady

Tags: android, android-glide, android-bitmap

I am trying to load images from URL and set it as wallpaper. I am not getting any crash on testing but firebase reports show the following in production

```
Glide.with(this)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(full)
            .dontTransform()
            .format(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().fitCenter())
            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    Bitmap dstBmp;

                    if (prefs.getBoolean(SETTINGS_SCROLLABLE_WALL_KEY, false)) {
                        int width = resource.getWidth();
                        width = (width * displayHeight / resource.getHeight());
                        dstBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resource, width, displayHeight, true);

                    } else {
                        dstBmp = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(resource, sharedpref.DisplayWidth(), sharedpref.DisplayHeight());
                    }


                    WallpaperManager wallManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    try {

                        wallManager.setBitmap(dstBmp);
                        fabProgressCircle.beginFinalAnimation();
                        fab.setClickable(true);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(Fullscreen.this, "Error applying image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
```

And these are the errors that show upon on Firebase

```
Fatal Exception: com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.e: Unexpected exception thrown by non-Glide code
   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob.callCallbackOnResourceReady + 154(EngineJob.java:154)
   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineJob$CallResourceReady.run + 398(EngineJob.java:398)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 873(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 99(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 193(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6724(ActivityThread.java:6724)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 495(RuntimeInit.java:495)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 858(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I guess this one followed by the above error shows that the height or width of the bitmap returned by Glide is 0

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap + 1033(Bitmap.java:1033)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap + 1000(Bitmap.java:1000)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap + 950(Bitmap.java:950)
   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap + 871(Bitmap.java:871)
   at android.media.ThumbnailUtils.transform + 428(ThumbnailUtils.java:428)
   at android.media.ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail + 231(ThumbnailUtils.java:231)
   at android.media.ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail + 206(ThumbnailUtils.java:206)
```

And these errors never showed up on testing.

Comment: `resource` width and/or height can be 0. In case of height=0 you're getting `ArithmeticException` caused by dividing by 0. So just check if width and height > 0.

Comment: But how could glide return a bitmap with 0 height or width